# mysql how to join to fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

I have 3 table

Attribute

```
attr_id | attr_name 
1       | oval<
2       | white
```

Product

```
product_id|product_name 
1         | amazonite 
2         | agate
```

attr_detail

```
attr_detail_id | attr_id | product_id
1              | 1       | 1
2              | 2       | 1
3              | 1       | 2
4              | 2       | 2
```

Now I want product those are oval shape and white color. How to use join.

Comment: Search the web for `MySQL JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name 
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN attr_detail ad ON p.product_id = ad.product_Id
INNER JOIN Attribute a    ON a.attr_id = ad.attr_id
WHERE a.attr_id IN(1, 2);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3fdf/1)

This will give you:

```
| PRODUCT_ID |           PRODUCT_NAME |
---------------------------------------
|          1 |              amazonite |
|          2 |                  agate |
|          3 | Product has only white |
```

---

**Note that:** This will give you the products names that have either the `white` or `oval` shapes. *However*, if you are looking for only those products that has both the two shapes, you have to modify your query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name 
FROM Product p 
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT product_id
  FROM attr_detail
  WHERE attr_id IN(1, 2)
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr_id) = 2
) ad ON p.product_id = ad.product_Id;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3fdf/5)

This will give you:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | PRODUCT_NAME |
-----------------------------
|          1 |    amazonite |
|          2 |        agate |
```

---

Please read more about `JOIN`s. Here you can find a useful information about this:

- [**Join (SQL)<sup>From Wikipedia</sup>**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).
- [**Another Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- [**SQL Queries for Mere Mortals(R): A Hands-On Guide to Data Manipulation in SQL**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201433362), a great book for SQL Basics.

For what I did in the second query:

```
  SELECT product_id
  FROM attr_detail
  WHERE attr_id IN(1, 2)
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr_id) = 2
```

This is called [*Relational Division*](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: In your case it is giving all three products but i want product those have oval and white.

Comment: Thank u so much @mahmoud.
You explain very well this to me now i understand what i was missing.

Comment: @abhi - You're welcome any time. See my edit for more explanation :).

Comment: First time i got so detailed answer of my question.Thanks again @mahmoud for explaining joins to me.

Comment: Sure, i am reading all..